# Can a Discord bot copy message links?

Tags: javascript, discord, message

Im thinking about that my bot goes back for its own message from the past and sends its message link back after a few days.

Comment: please do some research before posting a question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a database and store the message-id and channel-id as a record in a table (assuming your using SQL). Then when you want to fetch again, just do

```
let channel = await client.channels.fetch('channelid')
let msg = await channel.messages.fetch('messageid')
message.channel.send(msg.url)
```

or you can simply store the URL then just `message.channel.send('your url')`